# FORTRAN how to skip a line while reading lines in a DO loop?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to read a file line by line using a DO and read to manipulate individual lines. However, I'm trying to skip a line wherever I see something I don't want.

Here's what I have so far:

```
DO J=1,10000
  READ(1,'(A150)') ROW
  IF (J==A(1)+1 .AND. ROW(17:17)=='|') THEN
    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:12) // ROW(15:150)
  ELSEIF (J>A(1) .AND. J<A(2) .AND. ROW(1:1)=='#') THEN
  ! Here's where I need to skip J and go onto J+1 and then continue the DO loop from there
  END IF
END DO
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Though a CYCLE statement will take you back to the beginning of the DO-loop, in your case, CONTINUE or no code at all will skip the line. Since you read a formatted file sequentially, each READ statement increments the record position by one. So, in your case, taking no action at all effectively skips that line. The code that you posted should do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use `CYCLE`:

```
DO J=1,10000
  READ(1,'(A150)') ROW
  IF ((J==A(1)+1) .AND. (ROW(17:17).EQ.'|')) THEN
    WRITE(2, '(A)') ROW(1:12) // ROW(15:150)
  ELSEIF (J.GT.A(1) .AND. J.LT.A(2) .AND. ROW(1:1)=='#') THEN
    CYCLE
  END IF
  ! More statements here
END DO
```

As Hristo pointed out, `CYCLE` is only necessary if you have more statements following the `IF ... END IF`.

Comment: `CYCLE` in this case does nothing - there are no other executable statements in the body of the loop after `END IF`.

Comment: @HristoIliev, Correct. I wrote this as if the OP might want to put more code after the `IF ... END IF`.

Comment: You should put something like `! More statements here` after the `END IF` to make it more clear that `CYCLE` is only necessary if there are statements following that have to be skipped.